# How to see that if the following integral is finite, the second moment is finite as well?

Tags: probability-theory

How to see that if for some random variable $X$
$$\int_0^\infty\sqrt{P(|X|> t)}dt<\infty,$$
then $E|X|^2<\infty$. To show this I have a hint that
$$E|X|^2\leq 2\int_0^\infty P(|X|\geq u)udu \leq 2\int_0^\infty\sqrt{P(|X|> t)}dt\|X\|_2.$$

The first statement follows, since
$$E|X|^2 = \int_\Omega|X(\omega)|^2dP(\omega) = \int_\Omega\int_0^{|X(\omega)|^2}dtdP(\omega) = \int_0^\infty\int_\Omega\mathbf{1}_{\{\omega:\;|X(\omega)|^2>t\}}dP(\omega)dt = \int_0^\infty P(|X|>\sqrt{t})dt=2\int_0^\infty P(|X|>u)udu.$$

I fail to see the second inequality.

Comment: Actually the first statement holds with equality. You can find it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_definition) for $a=2$

Comment: Yes, this is what is written below. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Yes, of course, your second line is always with "$=$" signs. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement seems to be incorrect.

For a counter-example take a random variable whose probability distribution behaves like $$\rho(x) \sim \frac{c}{x^{3} \ln^{2} x};$$
if you want to be concrete, you can take 
$$\rho(x) = \frac{c}{(x+2)^3 \ln^2(x+2)}$$
with $c$ a constant such that $\int_0^\infty dx\,\rho(x)=1$.

We obtain
$$p_t=P(X>t) = \int_t^\infty dx\, \rho(x) , \qquad p_t \sim \frac{c_1}{t^2 \ln^2 t}; $$
such that $\int_0^\infty dt\, \sqrt{p_t} $ diverges as $$\sqrt{p_t} \sim \frac{\sqrt{c_1}}{t \ln t}.$$

On the other hand we have
$$E(X^2) = \int dx\, x^2 \rho(x) < \infty,$$
as $$x ^2 \rho(x) \sim \frac{c}{x \ln^2 x}.$$

Note: for this analysis, you need the result that
$$ \int_{x}^\infty dt\, \frac{1}{t \ln^\beta t}$$
converges iff $\beta>1$.

Comment: Why the last integral converges? I seems to diverge as far as I can tell.

Comment: $1/(x \ln^2 x)$ has the antiderivative $-1/\ln x$...

Comment: Ok, so you use $x>0$.